# Articles before the names of sports

Tags: articles, nouns

I heard that the names of sports are common nouns . I think that they are abstract and uncountable also . Is that why we don't use any articles before them. Even if we consider it the case ,we should be able to use the definite article the second time we use the same noun. But I've never seen such examples

People say
'I am playing cricket'
and not
'They are playing the cricket '

Can you explain me how do people use the name of sports without an article .

Comment: I'm sorry about it.  It's just that i couldn't find an answer for a long time

Comment: I agree with James K in the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316634/articles-before-the-names-of-sports#comment594161_316634), don't demand answer, I already downvoted your post. Please avoid asking similar question like this.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question, I might even try to answer it at some point.  I don't think the answer is obvious

Comment: I think you have answered it already: they are abstract and uncountable, and we don't use articles before abstract and uncountable things.

Comment: [*She don't like **the** football!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+don%27t+like+the+football%22) The article there is syntactically "non-standard" (as is using ***don't*** instead of ***doesn't*** for a singular subject), but it's not at all uncommon in "lower-class" colloquial British English. I just flag this up by way of showing that the OP here *does* have a legitimate perspective, despite the completely unjustified downvotes.

Comment: @stangdon The sadness I feel from that statement is nothing compared to the joy that I hope you'll get from this counterexample (!)

Comment: @JamesK That is very true, and yes, you can play *a football* unlike any other football played anywhere else, but I was trying to make my point general and short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: If you can say "I like cheese and I am eating cheese" then you can say "I like cricket and I am playing cricket". There is no definite article.

The mistake you make is in applying a "first mention/second mention" rule, that doesn't really exist in English.  Look at this example with the non-count noun "cheese":

> I like cheese, but yesterday I ate cheese for breakfast lunch and dinner. Today the cheese has made me sick. So right now I don't want cheese!

Why did I use "the" in the third mention of cheese, but not the second or the fourth?  It is because in the third mention, I was referring to a specific quantity of cheese, the cheese *that I ate yesterday*.

So the number of previous mentions is not the reason for using "the". It is the definite identity of a specific quantity of cheese. A particular mass of cheese is definitely identified in the third use.

But with abstract nouns it is unlikely to have a specific quantity. So you are unlikely to use "the happiness", except in rather artificial constructions:

> The happiness that I feel today is tinged by melancholy.

The speaker is referring to a specific mass of happiness, so "the" is used. To force this I've used a relative clause "that I feel today" to definitely identify the happiness.

Normally you wouldn't use "the happiness"

> Happiness is very important. Many people find happiness by being with friends, but some people never find true happiness.

How about sports.  Well the names of sports are abstract non-count nouns. It is unlikely in most contexts that you can have a specific mass of cricket.  If you have "I like cricket and I am playing cricket"  it is just the same as "I like cheese and I am eating cheese".  There is no definite article.

Now it is possible to use the same trick with cricket that I did with "happiness":

> The cricket that we played on the beach was fast and enjoyable for everyone.

It is rather artificial, and you are unlikely to ever need it.  In nearly all cases when you use the word "cricket" you are referring to the game in general and not to a particular amount.

Normally if you do need to refer to a particular amount of cricket you will use a word like "match" or "season".

> People are watching the cricket match.

> The cricket season has been plagued by injuries to many of the star players.

Comment: So , definite article is used just for being specific ,but it is not used in a second mention situation .